# php array_intersect making issues and i'm not able to check the empty array

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, array-intersect

I have five arrays and a search for which user can do search randomly. So for among those five sometimes there may be value for two arrays, three arrays or five arrays and whatever.

So When I intersect I am not be able to check which are empty so that it always returns an empty array.

```
$full_ids = array_intersect($g_arr, $c_arr, $k_arr, $m_arr, $p_arr);
```

Actually I need to check and make this dynamic like if there are values for `$g_arr, $c_arr`then the above operation will be applied with these two.. like

```
$full_ids = array_intersect($g_arr, $c_arr);
```

I don't understand how to check that? Any help w'd be appreciated..thanks

Comment: Probably you have to use `array_diff`, not `array_intersect`

Comment: @hindmost I need the common values from those arrays...

Comment: Create a new, empty array; Test each array in turn, if it contains values then push to your new array; then use call_user_func_array() to call array_intersect() with your new array as the argument

Comment: It's hard to understand what you want. Could you provide example of source arrays and desired result?

Comment: @MarkBaker w'd you please write a sample here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$tempArray = [];
if (count($g_arr) >0) $tempArray[] = $g_arr;
if (count($c_arr) >0) $tempArray[] = $c_arr;
if (count($k_arr) >0) $tempArray[] = $k_arr;
if (count($m_arr) >0) $tempArray[] = $m_arr;
if (count($p_arr) >0) $tempArray[] = $p_arr;

$intersect = call_user_func_array('array_intersect', $tempArray);
```