# autofill arguments in function with items from array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, filtering, intersection, variadic

I need to compare all first levels items of a muli-dimensional array and get the intersection values.. But the array doesn't have a fixed number arrays to compare with each other..

Here you have to explicit type each argument in `array_intersect`..

```
$list = [
  [0,1,2],
  [2,5],
  [-1,2]
];

$t = array_intersect($list[0], $list[1], $list[2]);
print_r($t);
```

But what if the `$list` array had 10 sub-arrays and I wanted to compare each and one of them?

Comment: Do you want this effect? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12381085/array-intersect-a-variable-amount-of-arrays https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39398040/php-dynamic-array-intersect https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38056228/get-intersection-of-a-multiple-array-in-php

Comment: More: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43710980/array-intersect-with-dynamic-length-of-arguments https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14291340/array-intersect-inside-multidimensional-array https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9438057/array-intersect-but-for-a-sub-arrays-of-a-single-array-variable https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47201552/how-would-i-use-array-intersect-with-the-arrays-in-an-array https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22449442/php-array-intersect-making-issues-and-im-not-able-to-check-the-empty-array

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29031430/how-to-get-array-intersect-with-single-array-group https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37345560/php-comparing-and-extracting-common-array-elements

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`call_user_func_array`](https://secure.php.net/call_user_func_array) (< 5.6) or [`arguments unpacking`](http://php.net/manual/en/migration56.new-features.php#migration56.new-features.splat) (>= 5.6)

```
call_user_func_array('array_intersect', $list);

array_intersect(...$list);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using [`call_user_func_array`](https://php.net/call_user_func_array):

```
call_user_func_array('array_intersect', $list);
```